# Mails with job offers shouldn't include a job more than once

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

Recently I have received the same job request three times, in different emails. Can you change it so that a job is only included once in the emails?

Answer (score 4):

When an employer sends you a message, it is sent to your email address. Note that you can change this behavior in your [email preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences).

*If we don't hear back after 4 days*, we send you a reminder email, then another one 6 days later.

If you click on one of the "I'm interested" or "I'm not interested" links in the email, or if you answer the message, no reminder will be sent.

We don't offer to disable reminders currently, but I'll raise it with the team.

Comment: Well for what it's worth, I've just switched it all off, not because I would not like to get employer emails, but I never want to get mails multiple times. Reminders are for stuff like outstanding payments or events you've signed up for where you actually want to be notified. This just feels like spam. I don't even want to disable reminders, you know. There are already enough settings. I just think they are wrong in the first place.